# Can I SSH to Local Weblogic AdminServer via Command Line?

Tags: ssh, putty, weblogic12c

From Eclipse, when I startup my local Oracle Weblogic Server 12c to run my web application locally, I can visit the Weblogic AdminServer Console at localhost:7001/console. However is there way I can login to the AdminServer via putty with a Command Line interface?

What would my hostname or IP address be for the login, and my port would be 22? Then I would expect to use the same username and password I use to login to the Server console GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weblogic admin console does not listen on SSH protocol, the best you can do is log in to the local server where Weblogic is running, and access the scripting tool, via something like the following

```
wlst.sh
connect('weblogic','password','t3://localhost:7001');
```

And then run commands that Weblogic understands. The username and password you would have set up during installation. You can also invoke it from the command line via Java, as shown in the following tutorial.

[Weblogic Scripting Tool tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/06-WLST--4474/cmdline.htm)